# Number of rectangle of size x,y which cover a cell p,q

Tags: rectangles, multigrid

I have a rectangle of size n*m (Where n is a number of rows and m is the number of columns) which is divided into of size 1*1.

I want to calculate the number of the rectangle of size P*Q which contains the cell (x,y) in them.

For example a rectangle of size 3*3 where I need to find all sub-rectangle of size 2*2 which contains the cell (2,2).There will be total 4 such rectangle will be there
I may try to solve this by iterating through all cells and find if all points are reachable from this point but it is lots of time-consuming.
If any math formula is there which can help.

Comment: Is $P$ the number of rows in the covering rectangle, or can the covering rectangle be rotated?

Comment: yes, P is the number of rows and Q is the number of columns. It will not be rotated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $P$ is the number of rows in the covering rectangle, the rows run horizontally and $x$ is measured horizontally from $1$ you need the left corner of the covering rectangle to be in the range  from $\max(1,x-Q+1)$ through $\min(x,m-Q)$.  Subtract these and add $1$ to get the number of horizontal positions the covering rectangle can be in.  Similarly, the number of vertical positions is $1+\min(y,n-P)-\max(1,y-P+1)$.  Multiply these two and you are done.

Comment: Can you please explain how it is satisfying the above example. I am not able to figure out

Comment: We can just work in one dimension.  If you have a row of $9$ squares and want to cover the fourth with a three square segment, you can start at squares from $2$ to $4$, so there will be three choices.  The start is at $\max(1,4-3+1)=2$ and the end is at $\min(4,9-3)$=4.